# There is no current event loop in thread

Tags: python, multithreading, bots, telegram, telethon

I am trying to create an API that gets channels participants Telegram. I am using telethon API in python, I am getting this error

Runtime Error: There is no current event loop in thread

here is my code

```
import os
from threading import Thread
from flask import Flask, request
from telethon import TelegramClient

app = Flask(__name__)

api_id = os.environ['API_ID']
api_hash = os.environ['API_HASH']
client = TelegramClient("anon", api_id, api_hash)

async def follow(channel_name):
  # await client.connect()
  # await client(JoinChannelRequest(channel=channel_name))
  me = await client.get_me()
  print(me.stringify())
  channel_users = await client.get_participants(channel_name)
  return channel_users

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return  "I'm alive"

@app.route("/follow_channel", methods=["POST"])
def follow_channel():
  body = request.get_json()
  user_id = body["userId"]
  user_hash = body["userHash"]
  user_name = body["userName"]
  channel_name = body["channelName"]

  client.loop.run_until_complete(client.get_me())

  return "helllo"

def run():
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)

t = Thread(target=run)
t.start()
```

Comment: post the traceback

Comment: Before attempting to mix threaded and `asyncio`-based libraries, I recommend you first learn to mix barebones `threading` and `asyncio`. An easier route is to use an async alternative to Flask, such as Quart.

Answer (score 1):

Threads do not have an event loop, you simply need to use the main thread loop.

```py
t = Thread(target=run, args=[client.loop])
```

and simply put the loop in run

```py
def run(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    ...
```

This should solve the problem. If your problem freezes then I dont know how to solve it now.

Comment: I did this but server is not responding now

Comment: ok i will update code